# Find a degree-one generator for which $\times g : S/I \hookrightarrow S/I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to repair a [proof of Bezout's theorem](http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/chapter-6.pdf). To do so it would suffice to show the following algebraic fact; I'm hoping someone could either prove it or find a counterexample.

Let $S = \mathbb C[x_0, \dots, x_n]$, and let $I$ be a homogeneous ideal. Define the *saturation* of $I$ to be
$$ \overline I = \left\{ s \in S \mid \exists N : x_i^Ns \in I \; \forall i \right\}.$$
For example, the saturation of $(fx_0, fx_1, \dots, fx_n)$ is $(f)$.

Assume now $I = \overline I$. I want to show that there exists a $g \in S$ of degree one for which one obtains an injective map $$\times g : S/I \hookrightarrow S/I.$$ How might I do this?

(Side remark for algebraic geometers: contrary to linked PDF, I think it does *not* suffice to look at $\operatorname{Proj} S/I$ and select a $g$ for which the hyperplane $V(g)$ doesn't intersect $V(I)$. A counterexample in this case is $n=2$, $I=(x_1^2, x_1x_2)$ in which case $g = x_2$ is a bad choice. In this situation one should choose $g=x_0$ instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $I$ is a saturated ideal, then $\mathfrak m=(x_0,\dots,x_n)$ is not an associated prime of $S/I$ (why?). Then use the Proposition 1.5.12 from Bruns and Herzog.